# Why does my attempt to upload files result in a 405 error?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, filepond

I´m trying to upload one image with FilePond in Laravel 10 and using component in VueJS 3.

To try this, i´m doing this component:

```
<template>

    <file-pond
        name="back_dni"
        ref="pond"
        class-name="my-pond"
        label-idle="DNI trasero"
        allow-multiple="false"
        accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
        v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
    />
</template>

<script>
    import vueFilePond, { setOptions } from 'vue-filepond';
    import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.esm.js';
    import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type';

    import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
    import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css';

    const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginImagePreview, FilePondPluginFileValidateType);

    setOptions({
        server: {
            process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);

                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf"]').attr("content"));
                request.open('POST', '/commercial/uploadDocuments');
                
                request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
                    progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
                };

                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                        load(request.responseText);
                    } else {
                        error('oh no');
                    }
                };
                request.send(formData);
                
                return {
                    abort: () => {
                        request.abort();
                        abort();
                    },
                };
            },
        },
    });

    export default {
        name: 'uploadDniBack',
        data: function () {
            return { 
                myFiles: [] 
            };
        },
        
        methods: {
            handleFilePondInit: function () {
                this.$refs.pond.getFiles();
            },
        },
        components: {
            FilePond,
        },
    };
</script>
```

I´m building a `FormData` and append into my token and image. **My problem it´s that always return 405 error**.

My route it´s defined as `POST` and here it´s my definition:

```
POST   commercial/uploadDocuments commercialuploadDocuments › Commercial\CommercialPreContractController@upload…
```

I don´t know that i´m doing wrong but always return 405. it´s my firt time with this library.

I shared with all, all my code in my component, so save time.

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question about your problem.

Comment: @isherwood i change my title and clear my javascript code. I hope that now it´s more readable

Comment: Your title isn't specific, isn't a question, and isn't properly capitalized and punctuated. Did you read that page? Ask a question _about your problem_. Don't just vaguely describe your project.

Comment: Your question would benefit from some more debugging information. Start by using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. Are you actually making a POST request or is it some different kind of request (such as OPTIONS or PUT)? Given that information, you could refocus your question so it is less end-to-end: Is this a JS problem where you aren't getting the POST request you expect or is it a PHP/Laravel problem where the POST request isn't getting the response you expect?

Comment: 405 can happen on some backend when the ContentType is not valid (either input or output). Could you print the headers ?